# What I might be doing wrong here while converting the date?

Tags: php, php-7.0

I simply just want to convert the date in PHP. I am using PHP 7.0.33. It was working fine before but suddenly it started producing a **Fatal error**

Below is my code.

When I use `format()` I get

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on boolean

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $dates[$i]);
$date = $date->format("Y-m-d");
```

Any help will be great!!

Comment: `var_dump($dates[$i])`

Comment: A **Fatal error** you say?

Comment: your $dates[$i] type is boolean, the error already told you whats wrong

Comment: As @A.Marwan said, the error gives you the clear information that you're trying to format with boolean value, echo the `$dates[$i]` and let us know the result

Comment: $dates is boolean but not $dates[$i]

Comment: Can you post all your code here so we can investigate it?

Comment: DateTime::createFromFormat returns FALSE on failure.

Comment: Enable error reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` so you see the reason for the failure.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime::createFromFormat() returns FALSE in case of error, so the problem is in this function call. Check the value of $dates[$i].